# AWS CDK - DockerImageAsset - How to use published ECR image in a downstream image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

We currently have "base images" that our downstream containers pull from and we are in the process of upgrading from bespoke CDK pipelines to simple CDK pipelines using `aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr-assets`. We had been doing this by sharing the URI of these base images using SSM as they are in separate projects & stacks.

I have been attempting to do this by importing the SSM into the downstream stack and passing the URI as a Buildarg, but I'm running into "Cannot use tokens in keys or values of "buildArgs" since they are needed before deployment", which as per issue [#3981](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3981) is as intended.

This makes me think I'm doing this wrong, but I'm not sure what the best practice is to achieve this? I'm working around this by hard-coding the URL that is stored in the SSM, and obviously I could pre-fetch this and pass it in at runtime but that seems clunky.

The architecture I was trying to achieve is like this:

Upstream stack:

```js
const pythonDocker = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'python-3-base-image', {
    directory: join(thisDirectoryInSrc, '/python-3'),
    ignoreMode: IgnoreMode.DOCKER,
});

new StringParameter(this, 'python3-ecr-arn-ssm', {
    stringValue: pythonDocker.imageUri,
    description: 'Python 3 image repository URI',
    parameterName: '/docker-images/python-3/image-uri',
});
```

---

Downstream stack:

```js
const baseImage = StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(this, 'python-3-base-image', '/docker-images/python-3/image-uri');

const feedReaderDocker = ContainerImage.fromAsset('src/feed-reader', {
    ignoreMode: IgnoreMode.DOCKER,
    buildArgs: {
        BASE_IMAGE: baseImage.stringValue
    },
});
```

Downstream Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM BASE_IMAGE

# Install dependencies, declare entry point, etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Use context. The `StringParameter.valueFromLookup` "context method" can retrieve and cache the previously deployed Parameter value at synth-time.

As you experienced, `StringParameter.fromStringParameterName` resolves at deploy-time.  But `ContainerImage.fromAsset` needs the resolved base image value at synth-time.  CDK gives us [Runtime Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) for this use case:

> The AWS CDK supports several context methods that enable AWS CDK apps to obtain contextual information from the AWS environment... If a required context value isn't available, the AWS CDK app notifies the CDK Toolkit that the context information is missing. The CLI then queries the current AWS account for the information, stores the resulting context information in the cdk.context.json file

[StringParameter.valueFromLookup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#static-valuewbrfromwbrlookupscope-parametername) is one such "context method".  Here's an example that compares the synth-time values of the two methods:

```js
const paramName = '/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version';
const fromName: ssm.IStringParameter = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(this, 'FromName', paramName);
const fromLookup: string = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, paramName);

console.dir({ fromName: fromName.stringValue, fromLookup });

// -> { fromName: '${Token[TOKEN.196]}', fromLookup: '12' }
```

`valueFromLookup` fetches the value once with an SDK call and caches it in `cdk.context.json`.  CDK recommends you commit this file to adhere to the [deterministic deploy best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).

Comment: Hi! Would you be so kind to elaborate on how this actually works? As the documentation states it "[...] obtains contextual information from the AWS environment [...]". How can the current, build-time only, value be obtained from the AWS environment? Or is this just some custom handling of sorts so the lookup is first done "locally"? I hope the question is somewhat understandable, thanks in advance!

Comment: @MarcesEngel Locally, at synth-time, the `StringParameter.valueFromLookup` method calls the SDK's `SSM.getParameter` method to get new (uncached) parameter values from the cloud.  The implementation details are available in the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/cea1039e3664fdfa89c6f00cdaeb1a0185a12678/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ssm/lib/parameter.ts#L391).